How do I validate a while loop and repeat based on conditions
Please help! I am stuck. No matter what I do the script doesn't execute correctly. Any insight is appreciated.
#!/bin/bash

Name=""
User_Number="0"

read -rp "What is your name? " Name
read -rp "Enter a number between 1-10. " User_Number

while (($User_Number <= 0 && $User_Number >= 11)) 
do
echo "The number you entered is invalid. Please try again." 
read -rp "Enter a number between 1-10. " User_Number
continue
echo "Hey ${Name}, the number you entered is: ${User_Number}."
done

while ((1 >= $User_Number <= 10)) 
do
echo -e "\nHello ${Name}!"
echo "The number you entered is: ${User_Number}"
break
done

If the user's number is outside of 1-10 I want them to prompted to enter a new number.  What's happening is when I test it out any numbers outside the range are treated as if they are in range.
I've tried rearranging the while loops to place one before the other to no avail. I've tried nesting them together through a while true if/then statement and that didn't work either. What am I overlooking? I've tried looking through other posts for help. Thanks.
btw I'm new to bash scripting

$User_Number <= 0 && $User_Number >= 11

In the first while loop, you have && (meaning AND) when you should have || (meaning OR). In the second while loop, shell expressions don't chain comparisons like that, so you need to use while ((1 >= $User_Number && $User_Number <= 10)). But actually, I don't know why the second while loop is even there, since if it makes it past the first (corrected) while loop, the condition will necessarily be true, and the break means it'll always execute exactly once (and the point of a loop is that it can execute multiple times).

Thanks guys! I figured out my mistake with && as opposed to || (and/or) but forgot to update here.

In the future, learn to check your code at https://shellcheck.net before posting. Be sure to include #!/bin/bash (or whatever you are using) as the first line. If you still have problems, post the shellcheck corrected code with a note that you have used it. Good luck.

You don't need the end of the script. My script uses -lt for less than and -gt for greater than, too. You should check out the correct syntax for this kind of comparison. Also, think about the use of && vs. || (you can't be both greater than and less than).
#!/bin/bash

Name=""
User_Number="0"

read -rp "What is your name? " Name

read -rp "Enter a number between 1-10: " User_Number

while [[ $User_Number -lt 1 || $User_Number -gt 10 ]]
do
  echo "The number you entered is invalid. Please try again." 
  read -rp "Enter a number between 1-10: " User_Number
done

echo "Hey ${Name}, the number you entered is: ${User_Number}."


As indicated in comments, your main issue is using && in first loop.
The second loop is not only unnecessary, and also contains a wrong syntax (or more precisely: not doing what you were expecting):
((1 >= y <= 10)) is equivalent to (( (1 >= y) <= 10 )). (1 >= y) is a boolean, which evaluates to 0 or 1. Your (( 1 >= x <= 10 )) expression is therefore always true, whatever x value is.
Note also that printf is preferred to echo, and that $ is unnecessary for variables in arithmetic expressions, such as inside ((...)).
To avoid asking the number twice in code, you can emulate a do-while loop, one possibility could be :
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare Name="" User_Number=0

read -rp "What is your name? " Name

for (( ; ! User_Number; User_Number = 0 )); do
    read -rp "Enter a number between 1-10. " User_Number
    (( User_Number > 0 && User_Number < 11 )) && break
    printf "The number you entered is invalid. Please try again.\n"
done

printf "\nHello %s!\nThe number you entered is: %d\n" "$Name" "$User_Number"

